# getting mixed results when checking if sslv3 is enabled on remote server

Tags: php

I am using the following php code to detect if sslv3 is enabled on a remote server, the code works fine but i found it gave mixed results when compared to a standard openssl command to do the same

Example host to scan: www.itunes.com

PHP code:

```
  $stream_sslv3 = stream_context_create (array("ssl" => 
    array("verify_peer" => false,
      "capture_session_meta" => true,
      "verify_peer_name" => false,
      "allow_self_signed" => true,
      'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv3_CLIENT,
      "sni_enabled" => true)));
  @$read_stream_sslv3 = stream_socket_client("sslv3://www.itunes.com:443", $errno, $errstr, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $stream_sslv3);
  if ( $read_stream_sslv3 === false ) {
    echo '     SSLv3 disabled';
    echo "\n";
  } else {
    echo 'SSLv3 enabled';
    echo "\n";
  }
```

A var dump shows the following, indicating it was able to connect?

`var_dump($read_stream_sslv3);`

> resource(16) of type (stream)

However, if i use openssl on the same machine, sslv3 is disabled on the remote server and the connection fails:

`openssl s_client -connect www.itunes.com:443 -ssl3`

Result:

> 22888:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake
>   failure:.\ssl\s 3_pkt.c:598:
>   no peer certificate available

Also, other server checking tools report that sslv3 is disabled on www.itunes.com so I wonder why my php code is saying it is enabled ??

Is something wrong with the php code?

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? I just executed the code on my machine (PHP 5.6.7) and it gave me the `SSLv3 disabled` message.

Comment: I guess this could also depend on the openssl version PHP has been compiled with - could you check with `php -i | grep openssl` and compare the used openssl path with the one `which openssl` refers to? (I have no clue what the issue might be, just fishing here :) )